# Problems making UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

Hi, I'm new to Xcode programming and I'm a bit confused while creating a `UITableView`.

I was reading lots of tutorials and I have created a subclass of `TableViewController`.

I already have a `UIViewController` with a xib file containing a `UITableView` inside.

I've implemented the necessary methods in the `TableViewController` subclass but I don't know how display show that `TableView` on screen.

I tried setting the table delegate to the `TableViewController` but the table doesn't show and it's linked by `IBOutlet` to a property on my `UITableView`.

Please someone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Sorry for my bad english

EDIT:
Really thanks for your help

Here is my code for that method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    FichaItem * item = [sucursales objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    cell.textLabel.text = [item.campos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [item.datos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

I really can't see what's wrong, that code is almost copied and modified to show my data.

Comment: If you are planning using xib, don't use TableViewController subclass just usual UIViewController. Don't forget to change the identity and hook up the delegate and dataSource from Xib.

Comment: check [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800355/uitableview-grouped-iphone-development) This link's answer show all type of table with source code and explanation Hope this helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

**Way 1** *(I'm doing it this way)*:

Open you viewController.h and inherit the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource protocols. This looks like this: `@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>`

Then open the XIB, drag a UITableView object into your view and hook it up: right-click-drag from the tableView to the file's owner object on the left hand side. Select Delegate and redo it for dataSource.

Then you only need to implement the delegate methods. You won't need to subclass UITableViewController

**Way 2**

Subclass UITableViewController.
Drag a UITableView into your view and add an "Object" to your XIB. Then set its class to your tableViewController subclass and hook it up with the tableView.

There might exist several more ways to do it. But these are the ways I'm familiar with.

***EDIT:***
Here is an example implementation of one delegate method.

```
NSArray *dataSource = @[@{@"title": @"myTitle", @"subtitle": @"mySubTitle"}, @{@"title": @"some other title", @"subtitle": @"some explanation"}];

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"reusableCell"];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"reusableCell"];
    }

    // dataSource is an NSArray of NSDictionaries
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[[dataSource objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:@"title"]];
    [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[[dataSource objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:@"subtitle"]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Doing it by first way it shows the table but when i scroll down and then back up the data disappear, can someone explain why?

Comment: This might be caused by UITableViews reusable cells. I'll try to put together some code for you